# All conditions are working where as one condition should run at one time CASE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My desired result is to get all customers from companies table with the id column and text column. Text column should contain id,name and phone number combined as this column will populate drop down in UI.

Now when a user search for specific number in dropdown then first it should be checked against id. If the record exists against that id then fetch the record for that id. If record against that id does not exists then query should search for record against phone number containing that search term.

I wrote that query(below) according to the scenario explained above, But the query returns all results where id is like `3%` and where phone is like `3%` simultaneously, Whereas I want to search against id or againt phone at one time.

Please help me to solve issue, Thanks

```
SELECT `id`, CONCAT(id, "-", `name`, "-", phone) as text
FROM `sma_companies`
WHERE ( ( CASE WHEN `id` LIKE '3%'
               THEN `id` LIKE '3%'
               ELSE `phone` LIKE '3%'
          END)
      ) AND
      `group_name` = 'customer'
ORDER BY `id`;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: +Gordon Linoff check my updated description again.

Comment: Why not simply break into two queries in your application code. First check for `id` only; if no results found, then only move to second query checking for `phone`. This will be significantly efficient than any other subquery based complex solutions..

Comment: +Madhur Bhaiya Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` expression is equivalent to `id LIKE '3%' OR phone LIKE '3%'`, because when the `id LIKE '3%'` is false, it goes into the `ELSE` clause and that tests `phone`.

If you only want to test `id`, don't use `CASE`, just perform that one test.

```
SELECT `id`, CONCAT(id, "-", `name`, "-", phone) as text
FROM `sma_companies`
WHERE `id` LIKE '3%' AND `group_name` = 'customer'
ORDER BY `id`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a prioritization.  Something like this:

```
SELECT c.id, CONCAT_WS('-', c.id, c.name, c.phone) as text
FROM sma_companies
WHERE (c.id LIKE '3%' OR
       (c.phone LIKE '3%' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM sma_companies c2 
                    WHERE c2.id LIKE '3%'
                   )
       )
      ) AND
      group_name = 'customer'
ORDER BY id;
```

That is, only check the phone if nothing exists for the id.

Comment: Getting error " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 1
                   FROM sma_companies c2 
                   WHERE c2' at line 5"